# Circle on image hover efect

Tags: html, css

I want to have a picture that will look like this (background should be white - not transparent like in my pic):

[image]

And when I hover with the mouse on that picture, circle should fully expand and show my original picture that will look like this:

[image]

In order to do that I try something like this:

```css
#myimage{
    background-color: #679b08;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    
    animation: expand-in .5s ease-out;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  }
  #myimage:hover{
    animation: expand-out .5s ease-out;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  
  @keyframes expand-in{
    0%{
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    100%{
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      border-radius: 60px;
    }
  }
  @keyframes expand-out{
    0%{
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      border-radius: 60px;
    }
    
    100%{
      width: 600px;
      height: 200px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id ="myimage">
<img width="600" height="445" src="http://i.prntscr.com/cC-VFJNfRbqxjohddP9AGw.png">
</div>
```

Here is also the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/bq89efr8/

Problem is that my circle in behind picture and it won't properly center and show my picture, I would like to work this only on CSS and HTML (althou I don't mind using some jquery) if possible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use animations? You can do this using the CSS `transition` attribute on the image inside your `#myimage` div.

```css
#myimage{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Verdana;
  }
  #myimage img {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  #myimage img:hover {
    border-radius: 0%;
  }
```

```html
<div id ="myimage">
<img width="600" height="445" src="http://i.prntscr.com/cC-VFJNfRbqxjohddP9AGw.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you move this to a stack overflow snippet? (rather than external site)

Comment: This is the best and easy solution, thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS. It includes browsercompatible webkit.

```
img{
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.25s;;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.25s;;
}

img:hover{
 border-radius: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use border-radius and :hover to get desired result.

```css
img{
 border-radius: 50%;
 transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

img:hover{
 border-radius: 0%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/64/64/animals?t=1513765419166"/>
```

**Edit** Added `transition-duration: 0.25s;` to add the desired animation effect

Comment: Added transition-duration: 0.25s; to add the desired animation effect

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wjk3z34o/) is a solution (with transitions).

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: border-radius 1s;
}
img:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.prntscr.com/cC-VFJNfRbqxjohddP9AGw.png" width="600" height="445">
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution would be to use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` properties.

Basically, you trigger the event when ever you point your mouse on the image, or outside the image. You can use that to change the border-radius of image.

```js
    function normalImage(image){
    image.style.borderRadius = "0%";
    }
    
    function roundedImage(image){
    image.style.borderRadius = "50%";
    }
```

```css
img{
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
 <img onmouseover="normalImage(this)" onmouseout="roundedImage(this)" width="600" height="445" src="http://i.prntscr.com/cC-VFJNfRbqxjohddP9AGw.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the following

```
#myimage {
background-color: #679b08;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 320px;
height: 320px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 300px;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: Verdana;
animation: expand-in .5s ease-in;
animation-delay: 0s;
background-image: url('http://i.prntscr.com/cC-VFJNfRbqxjohddP9AGw.png');
background-size: cover;
}

#myimage:hover {
animation: expand-out .5s ease-out;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes expand-in {
0% {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
100% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    border-radius: 300px;
}
}

@keyframes expand-out {
0% {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    border-radius: 300px;
}
100% {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
}
```

Then change your HTML to

```
  <div id ="myimage">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo element and the image as background so you avoid stretching the image with animation and you can easily control the position of the circle by adjusting top/right/bottom/left values .

```css
#myimage {
  background-color: #679b08;
  position: relative;
  height: 445px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

#myimage:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 120px;
  left: 120px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(http://i.prntscr.com/cC-VFJNfRbqxjohddP9AGw.png);
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#myimage:hover::before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myimage">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understood... I thougth it had to be a circle. (full screen to see it at real size)

```css
#myimage{
    background-color: #ffff;
    text-align: center;
    height:547px;
    width:547px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
  }
#myimage img{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
  position:relative;
  left:-138px;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}
#myimage:hover img{left:0;}

#myimage:hover{
    width:823px;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div id ="myimage"><img src="http://i.prntscr.com/cC-VFJNfRbqxjohddP9AGw.png"></div>
</div>
```